# Update lodash and graceful-fs 4.0.0

Tags: cordova

I just downloaded PhoneGap desktop and CLI, and I am trying to install it. My problem comes when, in cmd, I write `npm install -g phonegap@latest`. Throws an warn that sais that lodash@^3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0. The same goes to graceful-fs.

This looks easy to solve, but I just can't figure out how. I've tried everything.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have the Nodejs version 4.4.3 and Git 2.8.1

Comment: Does [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491905/npm-warn-deprecated-graceful-fs3-0-8-graceful-fs-version-3) address your question?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

```
npm install -g graceful-fs graceful-fs@4.1.3 

npm install -g graceful-fs lodash@4.0.0
```

For Linux add sudo at the beginning of each line.

More info on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532464/2961878).

Answer (score 0):

Both lodash & graceful-fs warnings aren't of your concern until they are explicitly mentioned in an error.
For now you can file the bug if you wish. It's not your problem.

For more information check out this stackoverflow question and the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35532464/3540057